HP laptop wont wake from sleep
I am running Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS x86_64 , On a HP Victus laptop. with a core i5-12450H, With iGPU Intel Alder Lake-P GT1 UHD Graphics, and a Dgpu RTX 3050M.
My laptop will not wake from sleep, They keyboard lights up but screen refuses to turn on. It seems to be an issue with the motherboard in this laptop not supporting the right kind of sleep state? I got it to work once in manjaro but I cannot for the life of me find or figure out how I fixed it then and was hoping someone in the Ubuntu community could help me resolve this issue since I've switched back to Ubuntu again.
I have been searching the site and online If I missed the answer just a link would definitely help me out.
Thanks in advance!
